# How to display custom message

Tags: magento2.2, success-message, ajaxaddtocart

I want to display a custom message on product page after Ajax add to cart success message in list page. Can you suggest anyway?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you do actually?
1. Add div after add to cart button
2. Add text message after the success message

Comment: I want add custom message in div..after addtocart success message..

Comment: Use [this extension](https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-custom-message-display-on-cart-checkout-success-page.html). It lets you add custom message to cart, checkout & order success page. You can also use attributes and conditions to display the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin or event/observer to update the success message.

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_add">
    <observer name="updatemessage" instance="{Vendor}\{Module}\Observer\UpdateMessage" />
</event>
```

In observer, Use \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface to get last added message and add new/updated success message.

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Observer/UpdateMessage.php

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class UpdateMessage implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface */
    protected $messageManager;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
    protected $url;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $managerInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $managerInterface;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $messageCollection = $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
        $customMessage = '<div>Your Message Here</div>';
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess($messageCollection->getLastAddedMessage()->getText() . '  ' . $customMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need this message in list page.(Ajax Addtocart)

Comment: @ManoM please add all the information in your question.

Comment: Ok ...I will update....

Comment: @ManoM It's common add to cart event. You can customize on your way in that code.